# Merge specific keys in a multidimensional array into one-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a complex data that structure I want to simplify.

This array depth may change since it's dynamic data coming from external resource.
I want to merge all arrays that has key `price` into one dimensional array.

I want to turn this:

```
array(
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name'  => 'Due',
    'product'    => array(
        'title'   => 'Product #1',
        'price'   => '90',
        'product' => array(
            'title'   => 'Product #2',
            'price'   => '90',
            'product' => array(
                'title' => 'Product #3',
                'price' => '90',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'misc'       => array(
        'country' => 'United States',
        array(
            'product' => array(
                'title' => 'Product #4',
                'price' => '90',
            ),
        )
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Product #5',
        'price' => '90',
    )
);
```

Into this:

```
array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Product #1',
        'price' => '90',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Product #2',
        'price' => '90',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Product #3',
        'price' => '90',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Product #4',
        'price' => '90',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Product #5',
        'price' => '90',
    ),
);
```

I thought a simple way to do it would be using `array_walk_recursive`, but found I cannot access the parent array.

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function( $value, $key ) {
        if ( 'price' === $key ) {
            // cannot access the parent array
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: [ask]. This is not a code-writing service, so you need to show us what you already tried first of all.

Comment: `'procuct'    => array(` – was that actually meant to be `procuct` here, or was that supposed to be `product` as well? (If the latter, then the demo array you have shown does not make much sense, because below that you have `'product'    => array(` again on the same level, so that second one would overwrite the first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Duei',
    'product' => array(
        'title' => 'Product #1',
        'price' => '90',
        'product' => array(
            'title' => 'Product #2',
            'price' => '90',
            'product' => array(
                'title' => 'Product #3',
                'price' => '90',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'misc' => array(
        'country' => 'United States',
        array(
            'product' => array(
                'title' => 'Product #4',
                'price' => '90',
            ),
        )
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Product #5',
        'price' => '90',
    )
);

function array_walk_recursive_full($array, $callback)
{
    if (!is_array($array)) return;

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $callback($value, $key);
        array_walk_recursive_full($value, $callback);
    }
}

$result = [];

array_walk_recursive_full(
    $array,
    function ($value, $key) use (&$result) {
        if (isset($value['price'])) {
            $result[] = [
                'title' => $value['title'],
                'price' => $value['price'],
            ];
        }
    }
);

print_r($result);
```

[working code example here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=686d51bcaffde65d49ac7f6c4157d2a8&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)